# Label offsetting in x86 GAS

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I have a short piece of code which declares an array of words, like this:

```
upper_mem: .word 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Now, I want to place the contents of the registers ax, bx, cx, dx in each of these locations but I'm not sure how the offsetting on the label works. Does the element position start from 0 (like in C) or 1? Say I wanted to do:

```
movw %bx, upper_mem(, 1)
```

Will that end up putting the contents of bx into the second word? Or do I do it with upper_mem(, 2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movw %bx, upper_mem(, 1)` is **NOT** anyhow the pendant of a C term `upper_mem[1]`. It is a syntactical exception and euivalent to `movw %bx, (upper_mem)` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory).

With the keyword `.word` and the following four values you reserved the place of 4 words (= 8 bytes) in the memory, but the assembler doesn't memorize it. The addressing remains **bytewise**. The first 2-byte element is at [memory+0], the second 2-byte element is [memory+2] and so on. If you load a word from [memory+1] you get a half of the first element and a half of the second element. A way for C-like indexing is to scaling (i.e. multiplying) an index register in your case by 2.

I hope the following example can point it:

```
# Name:             test.s
# Assemble & link:  gcc -m32 test.s
# Run:              ./a.out

.global main

.data
    upper_mem: .word 0, 0, 0, 0
    fmt: .asciz "%d %d %d %d\n"

.text
main:
    mov $10, %ax
    mov $20, %bx
    mov $30, %cx
    mov $40, %dx

# https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory
    movl $0, %edi
    movw %ax, upper_mem(,%edi,2)
    movl $1, %edi
    movw %bx, upper_mem(,%edi,2)
    movl $2, %edi
    movw %cx, upper_mem(,%edi,2)
    movl $3, %edi
    movw %dx, upper_mem(,%edi,2)

# https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html#i386_002dMnemonics
    movzwl (upper_mem), %eax
    movzwl (upper_mem+2), %ebx
    movzwl (upper_mem+4), %ecx
    movzwl (upper_mem+6), %edx

    pushl %edx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %eax
    pushl $fmt
    call printf
    addl $20,%esp

    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```